# making borders bold in r

Tags: r, border, polygon, tmap

I am trying to turn my current map (Map 1) into something like map 2, where the borough borders are bold, while the ward borders remain more faded. how do I do this?

[image]

[image]

This is my current code, and I am not sure how to make some of the borders bold

## plot the clusters

```
tm_shape(occupation_ward_sdf) +
  tm_polygons("occupation_LGO_G",
              style = "pretty", palette = GIColours,
              midpoint = 0, title = "Local Gi* statistic", alpha = 0.5
  )
  tm_layout(
    main.title = "Hot/Cold Spot Map of managers in London, 2014",
    main.title.fontface = 2,
    legend.outside = TRUE,
    legend.outside.position = "right",
    legend.title.size = 1,
    legend.title.fontface = 2
  ) +
  tm_compass(type = "arrow", position = c("right", "bottom")) +
  tm_scale_bar(breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), position = c("left", "bottom"))
```

Comment: parameter `lwd` of `tm_borders()` might be what you're after: https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap/reference/tm_polygons.html

Comment: ah I see, thank you. but if my data set is working with ward geometry, and not borough polygons, how would I go about making the borough borders stand out? would I need to somehow add these polygons to my data set, as I am currently working with the smaller ward polygons

Comment: If you are into vector spatial operations with R (which is fun; e.g. package {sf}), you can merge the wards by borough. Otherwise, there's ready-to-use data here: https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london

Answer (score 0):

Since all layers are stacked atop each other you can either use ready-to-use data as mentioned by @I_O (see `df_borough` below) or compute the borough polygons by your own by summarizing the ward polygons after grouping by column BOROUGH (see `df_borough_own` below). Both give the same result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# data from https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london
df_borough <- st_read("statistical-gis-boundaries-london/ESRI/London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp")
df_ward <- st_read("statistical-gis-boundaries-london/ESRI/London_Ward_CityMerged.shp")

# alternatively create borough data by your own and use instead of df_borough below
df_borough_own <- occupation_ward_sdf %>% 
  group_by(BOROUGH) %>% 
  summarise(union = st_union(geometry))

tm_shape(df_ward) +
    tm_polygons(col = "lightblue", lwd = .75) +
  tm_shape(df_borough) +
    tm_borders(col = "black", lwd = 1.5) +
  tm_layout(main.title = "Hot/Cold Spot Map of managers in London, 2014",
            main.title.fontface = 2,
            legend.outside = TRUE,
            legend.outside.position = "right",
            legend.title.size = 1,
            legend.title.fontface = 2) +
  tm_compass(type = "arrow", position = c("right", "bottom")) +
  tm_scale_bar(breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), position = c("left", "bottom"))
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate this help. but I still dont understand how I can add my data so that it is a hot/cold map. sorry im relatively new to r and my teacher didnt explain how to do this.

Comment: NEVERMIND. i have done it! thank you to both of you that helped me im so happy!!! this forum is incredible